# Show more comments

Tags: comments

I often visit the http://foo.bar drupal-based website, where occasionally pages contain more comments than the default layout shows. By default the adress of such a page is `http://foo.bar/node/2547/`. I want to set up my Chromium and my Iceweasel (of course they are the same as Chrome and Firefox in this scenario) to open `http://foo.bar/node/2547?comments_per_page=9999`. How to do that without modifying the browser sources? Notice I don't want to check how many comments there are, just show 9999 (or a similar large number). I don't want this behaviour to apply to other sites.

An additional question: what is the maximal value of `comments_per_page`?

Comment: Okay, please move it to there. I think my privileges aren't enough to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your Drupal site to display any number of comments you like, tough the UI does;t support all possibilities, any number is possible as it's a variable saved/gotten using `variable_get/set`

You can AFAIK not type something into the url to display all the comments on a page, just like you can't display all the users on this site. You can however tweak the url to display page 1, 2, 3 ... of the comments.